# How to mark a block of code in start repository page (readme.md)

Tags: markdown, bonobo

I use Bonobo Git Server 4.0.0.0 for Windows. It work fine. I use readme.md as information notice. I can mark a block of code using 4 spaces before every line (in this case syntax formating don't work). Unfortunately,

````
(empty line)
```java 
(some program code...) 
```
````

(or other program language) construction don't work for this markdown file. However, separate repository java files is parsed and displayed correctly in a Web browser. Maybe there's another way to mark code ?

Answer (score 1):

Fenced Code Blocks are not part of the [standard Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). They are a later addition which is not supported by all implementations. Therefore you need to determine which implementation you are using and whether that implementation offers support for the feature.

It appears that Bonobo Git Server uses [MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep) as its Markdown parser. According to MarkdownDeep's [documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/features#markdown-extra-enhancements), Fenced Code Blocks are not supported by default. Support for them needs to be turned on as part of [`ExtraMode`](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/api#net-edition). However, a quick perusal of Bonobo Git Server's docs does not indicate whether there is any server setting to enable that feature. As Bonobo Git Server's code is [opensource](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server) you could conceivably hack the code and run your own version. Or you could contact the devs of the project and request that the feature be added.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the syntax coloring to work without changes but for a fenced code block without coloring you can use the following:

```
~~~
<somecode></somecode>
<script src="yaddayadda"></script>
~~~
```

Apparently, ``` doesnt work while ~~~ does. However ~~~language doesnt work.